# move sprite when image is touched

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm new to iOS development and would appricate some help. I'm trying to move an image up the screen when ONLY the image is touched.

I've written the following code but when run images moves by touching anywhere on their screen:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    /* create spritenode and add rocket image */

    SKSpriteNode *sprite1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"rocket.png"];    
    sprite1.position = CGPointMake(400,400);

    SKAction *liftoff = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:1000 duration: 2];
    [sprite1 runAction:liftoff];

    [self addChild:sprite1];
}
```

Comment: Where is the code you have written, i.e. in what class have you overridden this method?

Comment: @hatfinch I would assume his current UIViewController, as he has not specified anything else.

Comment: I think it must be a subclass of SKNode, as this is the only class which responds to `-addChild:`. But I think whoever answers this question (not me, I don't know SpriteKit) will have to have a wider context than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me for now. I move Node when user moves finger left or right upon the battleShip SKSpriteNode.
Hope this will be helpfull.

```
#import "NewGame.h"

@implementation NewGame

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self == [super initWithSize:size])

   {
        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor blackColor];

        SKSpriteNode *battleShip = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship.png"];
        CGRect battleShipFrame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100);
        [battleShip setSize:battleShipFrame.size];
        battleShip.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 50);

        [self addChild:battleShip];
        _ship = battleShip; //@property (nonatomic, strong) SKSpriteNode *ship; in header file
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint currentLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self];
    CGPoint previousLocation = [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInNode:self];
    CGRect shipRect = _ship.frame;
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(shipRect, previousLocation))
    {
        CGPoint lvPosition = CGPointMake(_ship.position.x - (previousLocation.x - currentLocation.x), _ship.position.y);
        _ship.position = lvPosition; // works for me from Apple`s demo project

    //tried to use the under code - but it simpy moves spaceship away from screen)
    // so enden with simple setting the " position " property of SkSpriteNode
    // _ship   :

    //SKAction *moveNode = [SKAction moveByX:lvPosition.x y:0.0 duration:0.0];
    //[_ship runAction: moveNode];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I used the touchMoved event, it now appears be working fine.

Comment: I`m glad to be helpful)

Answer (score 0):

Change your method like below :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  if ([touch view] == ImageViewOfYourImage) {
    /* create spritenode and add rocket image */

    SKSpriteNode *sprite1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"rocket.png"];
    sprite1.position = CGPointMake(400,400);

    SKAction *liftoff = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:1000 duration: 2];
    [sprite1 runAction:liftoff];

    [self addChild:sprite1];
  }
}
```

where `ImageViewOfYourImage` is reference to your View where display your Image. Or you can use for check other property of [UITouch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object.

Comment: This is probably not what you want to do - this will create a new rocket sprite every time a touch is received, not move the old one like he wants.

Comment: @Matt Problem in question:  **images moves by touching anywhere**. My suggestion only limit code execution by matching condition touch the destination image. What's wrong?

Comment: yes, that's correct, I want to move the "rocket" sprite once clicked on, not create a new sprite.

Comment: @PaulGuymer before touch your "rocket" exist? where you create it? where you store reference to it?